# Does the JDK/JRE version alone determine the result of SSLSocket.getSupportedProtocols()?

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

Does the JDK/JRE version alone determine the result of SSLSocket.getSupportedProtocols()? Or are there any other configuration/startup parameters that can impact this result?

For example, if an application is running on JDK 1.7 update 21, this method will return [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]. But if the app ran on JDK 1.8, which does not support SSLv3, would this method return only [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]?

And I assume the answer to this question applies to the default enabled list as well. For example, in JDK 1.7 update 21, SSLSocket.getEnabledProtocols() by default returns [SSLv3, TLSv1]. So with JDK 1.8, would the default enabled list be [TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Prior to Java 7, you just had `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` to disable algorithms.

Starting in later versions of Java 7, you also have `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`.  The difference between the two seems to be that `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` can also restrict TLS/SSL versions.

`jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms` also exists.  Protocols on this list will only be used after all other allowed protocols have been rejected.

In Java 8u51, the defaults for these (found in Java's `lib/security/java.security` file) are:

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024

jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, DH keySize < 768

jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
        K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
        DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, \
        DH_RSA_EXPORT, RSA_EXPORT, \
        DH_anon, ECDH_anon, \
        RC4_128, RC4_40, DES_CBC, DES40_CBC
```

Comment: On a side note, SSLv2 was removed entirely on newer Java versions and cannot be used, hence why it doesn't appear in the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` list.

Comment: Is it the norm to configure the enabling/disabling of SSL/TLS protocols in this java.security file? Or should I handle this in the client code? That is, I would retrieve all supported protocols, then take out the ones I don't want (SSLv3, TLSv1) and setEnabled the rest.

Comment: @Zoomzoom You can really do it either way.  I do more web development than anything else, and it's pretty commonplace there to only list the protocols/ciphers you want to use.

Comment: On a side note, the [Java 8 Security Enhancements notes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html) mention that there's also a `jdk.tls.client.protocols` property new to Java 8 that can be used to restrict which versions of SSL/TLS the client will use.  It defaults to "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"

Comment: When you say "it's pretty commonplace there to only list the protocols/ciphers you want to use", you're talking about the java.security file? So it IS more common to modify that file rather than handle various restrictions in the app? I'm just trying to figure out what's best for the sysadmins using my software...

Comment: Also, I wonder why Oracle does not mention this java.security file on its [guide to remove SSLv3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html)?

Comment: I've asked a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31526390/1371217) about this.

Comment: @Zoomzoom Wow, must have missed this last year.  The version of Java that added `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` blocked SSLv3 using it by default.  Since it's the only setting in `java.security` that can block SSLv3, they didn't mention it.